# Get missing keys from ArgumentError when using @enforce_keys

Tags: elixir

### Problem

I have an example struct:

```elixir
defmodule Foo do
  @enforce_keys [:title, :description]
  defstruct @enforce_keys
end
```

If I create a struct without one of the keys while using `Kernel.struct!/2`, I get an ArgumentError:

```
attributes = %{description: "Lorem ipsum dolor..."}
struct!(Foo, attributes)
```

```
** (ArgumentError) the following keys must also be given when building struct Foo: [:title]
```

Is there a way for me to get a list of the keys that were missing while `rescue`ing the `ArgumentError`

```elixir
try do
  attributes = %{description: "Lorem ipsum dolor..."}
  a = struct!(Foo, attributes)
rescue
  ArgumentError ->
    # Can I get [:title]?
```

I'd like to create my own error message to pass back to a user, ie. "You must provide the following: title, ..."

### Solution 1

I can compare the keys of the map (`&2`) passed to `Kernel.struct/2` with the `@enforce_keys` attribute of the `Foo` module (exposing this using a function)

```elixir
defmodule Foo do
  @enforce_keys [:title, :description]
  defstruct @enforce_keys

  def required_keys, do @enforce_keys
end
```

and

```elixir
try do
  attributes = %{description: "Lorem ipsum dolor..."}
  a = struct!(Foo, attributes)
rescue
  ArgumentError ->
    Foo.required_keys -- Map.keys(attributes)
```

### Solution 2

I could define my own exception that contains the missing fields:

```elixir
defmodule FooError do
  alias Foo
  defexception missing_fields: Foo.required_keys
end
```

and raise it like this in `Foo`:

```elixir
defmodule Foo do
  import FooError
  @enforce_keys [:title, :description]
  defstruct @enforce_keys

  def required_keys, do @enforce_keys
  def new(map) do
    try do
      struct!(__MODULE__, map)
    rescue
      ArgumentError ->
        missing_keys = @enforce_keys -- Map.keys(map)
        raise FooError, missing_fields: missing_keys
    end
  end
end
```

with the resulting struct creation being changed to:

```elixir
try do
  attributes = %{description: "Lorem ipsum dolor..."}
  a = Foo.new(attributes)
rescue
  missing_fields in FooError ->
    missing_fields
```

but then I have to use `Foo.new` instead of `struct!/2`

**Is there a better way to do this?**

Comment: The main benefit of structs is for the compile-time checks, so I think you have picked the wrong tool for the job. Normally one would use Ecto for this. Check out embedded schemas and changesets.

Comment: Interesting — didn’t realize that Ecto was used without a database. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

As it might be seen in the [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) [source code](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.14.3/lib/elixir/lib/kernel.ex#L2382) for [`Kernel.struct!/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#struct!/2),
it [delegates](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.14.3/lib/elixir/lib/kernel.ex#L2345) to [`Map.replace!/3`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.14.3/lib/elixir/lib/map.ex#L393) which is a dumb wrapper for [erlang](/questions/tagged/erlang)’s `:maps.update/3`.

That’s the reason why with any other issue (like the wrong name of the struct,) it also simply raises [erlang error](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.14.3/lib/elixir/lib/kernel.ex#L2345) with only the `message` passed to the `ArgumentError`.

That said, you’d better off with your own implementation of `struct!/2`, doing whatever you want.